# How to say "how far is it between Bangkok and Moscow?" in russian

Tags: phrase

I want to know how to say "how far is it between Bangkok and Moscow?" in russian

Thanks.

Comment: Questions asking for translations are off-topic unless prior research effort is clearly indicated.

Comment: @alamar НАЗОВИТЕ ХОТЯ БЫ ПРИБЛИЖЕННО РАССТОЯНИЕ ОТ МОСКВЫ ДО ВАШИНГТОНА… [Василий Песков, Борис Стрельников. Земля за океаном (1977)]

Comment: @V.V. sounds archaic to my ear

Comment: @alamar, Entirely for you to train your ear. Расстояние от Москвы до города нашей мечты составляет примерно 2500 километров. [Саша Грибоедова. Амстердам Trip (2004) // «Хулиган», 2004.07.15]
- Ездить, изучать такие дистанции, как расстояние от Москвы до Владивостока,―это моя работа,―говорит Майкл в беседе с «КП». [Юлия ХОЖАТЕЛЕВА.
На автомобиле: расстояние от Москвы до Варшавы примерно 1300 километров. [Артем Локалов. Тариф польский – 52 тысячи в неделю // Советский спорт, 2011.12.27]

Comment: @V.V. All those three examples imply travelling and direction. But the original question doesn't imply direction.

Comment: Глагол "составляет" -это путешествовать? Тогда мы с Вами говорим на разных языках, и "sounds" --это не аргумент, кому sounds,a кому нет. И никаких правил я в Вашем ответе не вижу, а хотелось бы. "Also " обычно добавляется к чему-то. А у Вас к чему?

Comment: @V.V. к вашему ответу, который к тому моменту уже был.

Answer (score 2):

Каково расстояние от Бангкока до Москвы? --What's the distance from Bangkok to Moscow?

Comment: `между Бангкоком и Москвой` would sound more natural in this case, distance doesn't have direction.

Comment: @alamar Nevertheless you use `от Москвы до Бангкока` in your answer.

Comment: @Alex.S because travelling has direction but distances don't.

Comment: @alamar So you mean `сколько километров` is travelling but `каково расстояние` is not? Very interesting.

Comment: No comments. Слов нет. Пример из национального корпуса я дала под вопросом.

Comment: agree with alamar, logically this is how the question of distance has to be framed, the example from the corpus seems to recount a dialogue, and colloquialisms are at times alogical and not compliant with rules

Comment: А это для Вас. Расстояние от Москвы до Киева (трасса М3) – около 900 километров, из них примерно 250 километров – по Украине. [Артем Локалов. Какой курс у Евро?  Расстояние от Москвы до Варшавы примерно 1300 километров. [Артем Локалов. Какой курс у Евро?  // Советский спорт, 2011.11.18] 
Расстояние от Москвы до Тулы около 180 км. [Едем в Тулу и Ясную Поляну // Комсомольская правда, 2011.05.12]

Comment: @V.V. rules of logic and common sense,  if `Расстояние от Москвы до Киева – около 900 километров` then my question is what the `Расстояние от Киева до Москвы` would be, i'm not interested in `узус` but in logic, an `узус` may be alogical

Answer (score -1):

You can also specify desired dimension:

```
Сколько километров от Москвы до Бангкока?
Сколько часов лететь из Москвы в Бангкок?
```

It's actually preferred form for a native speaker.